# Creating a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 that will do a "facebook search"

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, full-text-search

I'm trying to implement a facebook search in my system (auto suggest while typing).
I've managed to code all the ajax stuff, but I'm not sure how to query the database.

I've created a table called People which contains the fields: ID, FirstName, LastName, MiddleName, Email.
I've also created a FTS-index on all those fields.

I want to create a stored procedure that will get as a parameter the text inserted in the query box and returns the suggestions.

For example, When I will write in the textbox the query "Joh Do"
It will translate to the query:

```
select * from People where contains(*, '"Joh*"') and contains(*, '"Do*"')
```

Is there a way to do that in stored procedure?

P.S
I've tried to use the syntax

```
select * from People where contains(*,'"Joh*" and "Do*"')
```

but it didn't returned the expected results, probably because it needs to search the words on different fields. Is there a way to fix that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
select   *
from     People
where    (FirstName  Like '%'+ @FirstName  + '%') and
         (MiddleName Like '%'+ @MiddleName + '%') and
         (LastName   Like '%'+ @LastName   + '%')
```

Also you may want to restrict the results to only return a maximum of say 10 by using:

```
select top 10
```

### EDIT 1:

OK I now understand the problem better. I would use dynamic sql thus:

First create a split function e.g. [Example Split function using XML trick](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-convert-split-delimeted-string-as-rows-using-xml.aspx)

**Then use dynamic sql:**

```
declare @tstr varchar (500)

set @tstr = ''

select  @tstr =@tstr + ' Contains(*, ''"'+ val + '*")' + ' and '
from  dbo.split(@SearchStr, ' ') 


set @tstr =  left(@tstr,len(@tstr)-4)

select @tstr
Declare @dsql as varchar(500)

set @dsql = 'select * from People where '+ @tstr

exec (@dsql)
```

Also please note as per Remus, be aware of SQL Injections, the use of  **sp_executesql** (instead of EXEC) would be better.

Comment: Then you lose the power of FTS, and your answer doesn't even describe how to do this with multiple values in a single text parameter to a SP...

Comment: I don't have the parameters separated. All I have is the string "Joh Do". I want the stored procedure to return the records for "John Doe" "Donald Johnson" etc.

Comment: Ok,thanks, I now understand the problem better, please see revised solution.

Comment: thank you very much, works great.
you only got one typo. you forgot to put '' at the end of the contains function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the open list nature of the argument. I can be `Joh`, it can be `Joh Do`, it can be `Joh Do Na` and so on and so forth. You have two main alternatives:

- parse the input in the web app (in ASP I assume) and then call an appropriate procedure for the number of entries (ie. `exec usp_findSuggestions1 'Joh'`, `exec usp_findSuggestions2 'Joh', 'Do'`, `exec usp_findSuggestions1 'Joh', 'Do', 'Na'`). The first procedure uses 1 `contains`, the second has 2 `contains .. and contains ...` and the last has 3. This may look totally ugly from a DRY, code design and specially code maintenance pov, but is actually the best solution as far as T-SQL is concerned, due primarily to the plan stability of these queries.
- pass the input straight into a single stored procedure, where you can split it into components and build a dynamic T-SQL query with as many `contains` as necessary.

Both solutions are imperfect. Ultimately, you have two problems, and both have been investigated before to quite some depth:

- the problem of passing a list to a T-SQL procedure. See [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005 and Beyond](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html)
- the problem of an undetermined number of conditions in the WHERE clause, see [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: I agree with everything you have said. However you have not given any solutions to the OP! But I have included same of your points in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The AJAX Toolkit has the "AutoComplete" control that provides this functionality out of the box.  It is very simple to use.

Look at a sample [here](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx)

Comment: Completely misses the OP's question